# Can't get a server socket to always listen to the client

Tags: c#, winforms, sockets, client-server

I'm making a little code in which I require the server to constantly receive a number from client. It does only one time but then stops listening. What's missing here?

**PS:** *I haven't closed any connections.*

Here's listening side (Server):[image]

Here's sending side (Client):[image]

Comment: How can I get the server to persistently listen to the client?

Comment: You are assuming that you will receive a whole int at a time. This is not a given. Use higher-level infrastructure like StreamReader.ReadLine. If you have to deal with ASCII it's a red flag you are doing something wrong.

Comment: I don't need the whole string. I just want an int.

Comment: What if Receive returns just the first byte? I can legally do that.

Comment: hi I've added the code on the client side. Do check that out & let me know if you have a solution. Moreover, both these functions are threads.

Comment: I don't know what the problem is, but I'm trying to tell you that TCP does not conserve "messages". If you send 10 bytes, you can get them split up arbitrarily from Receive (e.g. 1, 7, 2). You code will fail in that case.